# react native changes image if a function (that returns random image url) is passed as uri param & a state is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having a issue in react native where my images are reloaded whenever any state inside the render() changes. I'm passing a function (returns random image urls) directly into image uri. As I'm using nested lists & complex dynamic data, it is very hard for me to maintain separate variable for saving the image url & than pass it into image source. Is there ay work around for this issue.THANKS

```
Sample Code: UI
     <View>
     <Image  source={{uri:this.getImgUrl()}} 
     style={{ marginRight: 20, height: 200, width: 200 }} />
      <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
     <Button  title="ADD"  onPress={ this.setState({data:this.state.data+1})} />
     </View>

 /////////////////////Function///////////////
 getImgUrl(){  
 return {uri:'https://picsum.photos/200/300?date='+
          new Date().toLocaleString()
 };
```

}

Comment: Can you provide some code, is a little confusing for me what you try to achieve.

Comment: I've added some sample code above while I am using AWS function to get imgurl. Now whenever in my app I update a cart count  state variable , the image also reloaded ( in lists, all the images reloaded ). I dont get this thing that why react detect the image change when I call setState() to set cart values. Other things remain same, Only the images are loaded. I've a very complex list & creating variable for each image is also expensive. Kindl let me know how to update my UI cart values which are almost nested lists

Comment: I dont get that everytime I call setState(), react checks the img uri param & compare with older one. As aws generates unique img url, react rerenders the image. I need to stop this without adding any further variable as they will make app more slow

Answer (score 0):

The getImageUrl() function, uses new Date(). Hence when a state changes, the render function is called where the Image source is obtained using getImgUrl(). But new Date().toLocaleString() always gives the latest time in string format, which will not be equal to your previous new 
Date().toLocaleString() i.e your old and new URI's will not match. Hence new image will be loaded from the new URI everytime state changes.

```
getImgUrl(){  
 return uri:'https://picsum.photos/200/300?date='+
          new Date().toLocaleString()
 };
```

Save the URI as a variable somewhere, in componentDidMount() or constructor() etc.

Log the output of getImgUrl() for every render, and check if this is the root problem.

EDIT:

Use PureComponent from React,

> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result
>   given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a
>   performance boost in some cases.

```
class ProductImage extends React.PureComponent {

  render () {
    <Image  
      source={{ uri: this.getImgUrl() }} 
      style={{ marginRight: 20, height: 200, width: 200 }} />
  }

  getImageUrl () {
    return 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?date=' + new Date().toLocaleString();
  }
}
```

Use this component in place of your normal Image component, this way your image should render only once when the componentDidMount happens. Read more on PureComponent from google. Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed my url will change bcoz I'm using aws sdk where params changes everytime, but what if I dont want to save the urls as I have dynamic data & it will be an extra overhead to save the resolved image url for all images. I need to know is there anything better that I can do to surpass this situation & only change the image when I want.

Comment: React will never know that the image is the same every time.. React just knows that the source uri is different.. that's why react will re-render the image, it is a normal behavior..